Every collection of sets is the range of some family?
In Naive Set Theory by Paul R. Halmos, if I understand correctly, the term "family" refers to a function, particularly when we are more interested in its range than in the function itself. However, since a family is a function, its range must be a set. Later in the book, it is stated that every collection of sets is the range of some family.
Does this imply that every collection of sets must also be a set? If not, how can the statement that "every collection of sets is the range of some family" be valid?

See page 1:

Incidentally, to avoid terminological monotony, we shall sometimes say collection instead of set.

Thus, a collection of sets is simply a set of sets.
And yes, a family $\{ A_i \}$ is a function - i.e. a set - whose elements are pairs $(i, A_i)$, for $i \in I$. See page 34:

Observe that there is no loss of generality in considering families of sets instead of arbitrary colelctions of sets; every collection of sets is the range of some families.

This means that the two sets $\{ A_1, A_2, \ldots \}$ and $\{ (1,A_1), (2, A_2), \ldots \}$ are obviously different but for "practical uses" we may identify them, writing $\{ A_i \}$.
